# Is it safe to send the sensitive data with window.postMessage?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe, postmessage

Assume that, I have already setup two different domain, such as:

https://test1_example.com/

https://test2_example.com/

Test1 has an iframe with src of test2 site.

I would like to pass a username and password from test1 to test2 site, but I'm worry about whether someone will capture the sensitive data through the network during this process.
Should I encrypt it before using window.postMessage? As I'm not sure about whether the postMessage communication will go through the Internet, or just browser window communication.

Comment: If it's over an HTTPS connection data will be encrypted either way. What you're worried about is called a [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Answer (score 2):

**The data will not go through the network.**

The broadest route it can take is [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), (probable in your case, since thread isolation of cross-origin documents is very effective against timing-attacks à la Spectre), which is still completely internal to the computer.
If malicious scripts can intercept this, they can probably just read the content of both pages even more easily.

**However this doesn't mean you can send sensitive data through `postMessage()` carelessly**, far from it.

When sending sensitive data, you have to ensure that you are communicating with the page you expect to be communicating with. An other page than the one you expect could try to communicate with your page.

**Always set the `origin` parameter of `postMessage( msg, origin, [transferrable] )` to the origin of the page you want to communicate with.** Never use `"*"`, <sub>except if you are sure the data is not sensitive, AND you are in a hurry doing some tests</sub>.

Similarly, always check the [`.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/origin) of the MessageEvent received.  If you don't recognize it, ignore the message.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend not to publish sensitive data on a site unless you are sure about it.

Comment: the provided answer is vague and uses generalizations